# How to reduce compile time in an iOS project on CircleCI with COCOAPODS

Tags: ios, build, continuous-integration, cocoapods, circleci

There is an iOS application I am developing that use CircleCI for automatic testing and more CI operations. We did make it compile and run on the CircleCI but the compile time takes about 9 minutes. I need to reduce the compile time somehow. I thought about few options:

1. Use frameworks instead of CocoaPods. as the pods are being downloaded and installed on the CircleCi.
2. Use some caching on the Cocoa pods - We try without luck (See the code below of the YML).
3. Make the compiler compile only the changes that were made in code - This is a suggestion from a friend, I couldn't find some anything about it.

Part of YML code:

```
# Specify the Xcode version to use
macos:
  xcode: "9.2.0"
shell: /bin/bash --login -eo pipefail

steps:
  - checkout
  - run: git submodule sync
  - run: git submodule update --init --remote
  - run:

      name: Set Ruby Version
      command: echo "ruby-2.4" > ~/.ruby-version

  - restore_cache:
      key: 1-gems-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}

  - run: bundle check || bundle install --path vendor/bundle

  - save_cache:
      key: 1-gems-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      paths:
        - vendor/bundle

  - restore_cache:
      key: 1-pods-{{ checksum "Podfile.lock" }}
  - run:
      name: Install CocoaPods
      command: |
        curl https://cocoapods-specs.circleci.com/fetch-cocoapods-repo-from-s3.sh | bash -s cf
        bundle exec pod install
  - save_cache:
      key: 1-pods-{{ checksum "Podfile.lock" }}
      paths:
        - ./Pods

  # Build the app
  - run:
      name: Build app
      command: |
        export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
        export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        bundle exec fastlane match adhoc
        bundle exec fastlane adhoc

  # uploading app to testobject
  - run:
      name: Upload app
      command: |
        curl -u user -X POST https://testobject.com:443/api/storage/upload -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary @./builds/app.ipa
```

The pod file:

```
pod 'OpenCV2' // Problem transforming to framework as it is too large for github
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.9.3'
pod 'Apollo' // MATBE this can be a framework too
pod 'SwiftyJSON' // This can be a framework
pod 'RealmSwift', // This can be a framework
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Hero'
pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields'
pod 'MaterialComponents/AppBar'
pod 'Material', '~> 2.0'
```

Any suggestions on how to reduce the build time?

Comment: Did you reduce the compile time ?

Comment: Not yet. We put that task on the side for now. But to be able to proceed I have reduced the pods added them as Framworks so the CircleCI won’t download it over and over again

Comment: Hey, for me, using commands from your snipped which tells Circle CI to read/write cache of Gemfile and Podfile, did the trick. This works and definitely optimizes the whole build process. Thank you.

Comment: Great :) you can vote up so others will see it is helpful

Comment: @YevhenDubinin How did you do that? I want to exactly the same with my Gemfile and Podfile!